# Changing field placeholder text when invalid class exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a simple form:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First name *" required>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

If the required field is empty, the class `not-valid` is added to the input type text. If this `not-valid` class exists, I'm want to change the placeholder text to something else. So, a sample use case:

- User see's first name textfield (placeholder at this point says "First name *".
- User clicks submit, leaving textfield empty.
- Class `not-valid` at this point is added to the textfield.
- Placeholder now says "Please complete field" (in place of default placeholder").

Here's what I've got so far:

```
(function( $ ) {  

    $( document ).ready( function() {

        $('form').find(".not-valid").each(function(ev){
            if(!$(this).val()) { 
                $(this).attr("placeholder", "Please complete field");
            }
        });

    }); 

})( jQuery );
```

Doesn't change the placeholder currently.

Comment: i tested the code uo there its valid 100% 
the problem i mostly thing after adding the not-valid class 
the "find" function dosnt fire or things like you should post the full code in orderto debug the whole thing

Comment: yeah,  when you add 'class="not-valid"' to the input tag, it all seems to work fine. When is the class added? Can you check if the class is added? You probably run the check for the 'not-valid' before the 'not-valid' is added.

Comment: In doing this on an input with no label, the user then may not know what it supposed to go into that field, as it no longer says anything about "First name".

Answer (score -1):

Something like this? (I didnt use the not-invalid class, no need for that, unless you want to add other style to the empty filed)

```js
$('#submit').click(function()
{
    if($('#firstname').val() == ''){
      $('#firstname').attr('placeholder','Please complete field');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="First name *" required>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
</form>
```